# Convert Matlab NaN values to netCDF fill values

Tags: matlab, nan, netcdf

I'm using Matlab to create a netCDF file with NaN values in its variables.

Ideally I would like to substitute the NaNs of the Matlab variables by the default netCDF fill values when writing the netCDF. But I can't do it.

I understood from the Matlab doc that that's automatically done,

http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ncwrite.html

But it's not (I don't define any attribute). I guess the problem is very silly... but I can't find it.

This is basically what I'm doing:

```
A=1:20;
A(A<10)=NaN;

nccreate('file.nc','A','Format','netcdf4','Datatype','single','Dimensions',{'length' 20});

ncwrite('file.nc','A',A)
```

Checking file.nc with my viewer I find NaN values instead of the value of NC_FILL_SHORT defined in the netCDF library. But I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the complete code, including how you set `NC_FILL_SHORT`, to your question? From the part you put here, everything looks right.

Comment: Well, that's the important part. It that works the rest as well. But it's not working. `NC_FILL_SHORT ` is defined in the [netCDF library](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-c/Fill-Values.html).  It should be -32767. So I would expect to find that value instead of NaN which is determined by my matlab code.

Comment: I just found out that if I change the `Datatype` from `single` (what I'm using in my actual code) to `int16` (which is the correct one to use in my example) the netCDF output returns 0 instead of NaN...